# How to use react-native-testing-library getByRole

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to use `getByRole` in react native testing library but can't for the life of me figure out the syntax

Component in question-

```
<Text 
  accessibilityRole={'button'}
  accessibilityLabel={'upvote count'}
  style={[styles.upvoteText, styles.upvoteCount]}>
  {upvoteCount}
</Text>
```

and my code

```
expect(getByRole('button', {name: 'upvote count'} as MatcherOptions)).toBe(2)
```

Comment: Just a guess here, but is the role case sensitive?

Comment: it is but it was a type in my code i searched with both lowercase :D

Comment: It seems that the second argument of `getByRole` is ignored. With `getByRole('button', {name: 'someAccessibilityLabel'}` I get multiple button elements with different accessibility labels.

Answer (score 2):

So, I'm working on something similar. I saw this in [the docs](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-testing-library/docs/api/) to help with this case:

### In Component

```
<Text 
  accessibilityRole={'button'}
  accessibilityLabel={'upvote count'}
  style={[styles.upvoteText, styles.upvoteCount]}>
  {upvoteCount}
</Text>
```

### In Test

```
it('gets the button', () => {
  const { getByA11yRole, getByA11yLabel } = render(<Text>foo</Text>);
  
  expect(getByA11yRole('button')).toBeDefined();
  expect(getbyA11yRole('upvote count')).toBeDefined();
});
```

Comment: And yet, this example does not include the original question about the use `getByRole` function